# Convert many GET values to AJAX functionality

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I have built a calendar in php. It currently can be controlled by GET values ​​from the URL. Now I want the calendar to be managed and displayed using AJAX instead. So that the page not need to be reloaded.

How do I do this best with AJAX? More specifically, I wonder how I do with all GET values​​? There are quite a few. The only solution I find out is that each link in the calendar must have an onclick-statement to a great many attributes (the GET attributes)? Feels like the wrong way.

Please help me.

**Edit:** How should this code be changed to work out?

```
$('a.cal_update').bind("click", function ()
{
event.preventDefault();
update_url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
          type      : "GET"
        , dataType  : 'json'
        , url       : update_url
        , async     : false
        , success   : function(data)
                      {
                      $('#calendar').html(data.html);
                      }
    });
return false;
});
```

Comment: How familiar are you with using XmlHttpRequest in general? Perhaps you should dabble around with a smaller project to get a feel to how it works. Take a look at the Getting Started with AJAX docs at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/AJAX:Getting_Started

Comment: @nikc Actually, I know the basics. It's now when it's mixed into many click opportunities as it said stop in my head. I am most used to creat real-time feeds and stuffs like that with AJAX.

Comment: Ok, in that case, I'd like to point you to some (perhaps) new friends: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/ and http://mustache.github.com/. Also, looking up "form serialization" might help you find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Keep the existing links and forms, [build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)
2. You have existing views of the data. Keep the same data but add additional views that provide it in a clean data format (such as JSON) instead of a document format (like HTML). Add a query string parameter or HTTP header that you use to decide which view to return.
3. Use a library (such as YUI 3, jQuery, etc) to bind event handlers to your existing links and forms to override the normal activation functionality and replace it with an Ajax call to the alternative view.
4. Use [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to keep your URLs bookmarkable.

Comment: Really like the idea. It may just be too hard for me. But would love to read and learn more about what you mention above. Is there any dummies or beginner's guide on the internet that I can read? Or if you might want to show a basic example.

Comment: A [simple example](https://github.com/dorward/simple-ajax-demo) that does most of the above (although not pushState).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand so much of those files. I'm only familiar with html and php.

Comment: How do I "keep the existing links and forms" while adding jQuery? The big problem is how to convert the "link href GET values" into javascript variables to be sent with AJAX back to the calendar...I'm confused.

Comment: You use the event handling part of jQuery (e.g. [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind)) to attach an event handler that gets the href [attribute value](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), sets off the [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) request, and [stops the default action](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). You don't need to convert the "link href  GET values", you just use the URI as is.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you mean. But I edited my first post with the javascript code I working with. How should it look like with your method?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) string from the server and handle it with Ajax on the client side.